# The result of tf.ExponentialMovingAverage is not as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, moving-average

I would like to study how tf.ExponentialMovingAverage works. Here is the code:

```
w1 = tf.constant(10., dtype=tf.float32)
w2 = tf.constant(20., dtype=tf.float32)
w3 = tf.constant(40., dtype=tf.float32)
tf.add_to_collection('w', w1)
tf.add_to_collection('w', w2)
tf.add_to_collection('w', w3)

w = tf.get_collection('w')

ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.9)
ema_op = ema.apply(w)

with tf.control_dependencies([ema_op]):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in w:
            print(sess.run(ema.average(i)))
```

The results are :

```
1.0000002
2.0000005
4.000001
```

However, according to the formula in [tf.ExponentialMovingAverage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage#average), the results should be

```
0.9 * 0 + (1 - 0.9) * 10. = 1.0
0.9 * 1.0 + (1 - 0.9) * 20. = 2.9
0.9 * 2.9 + (1 - 0.9) * 40 = 6.61
```

It seems like tf.ExponentialMovingAverage does not update the shadow value using last shadow value, but calculates moving average independently for each iteration.

Am I thinking wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some misconceptions in your example:

1. The moving average is defined based on a variable or tensor. You effectively created moving averages for each of your constants (explaining the results you are getting).
2. You have to call `ema_op` every time you want to update your moving average.
3. The moving average is initialised with the initial value of your variable (not zero as you are expecting).

The following example behaves as you are expecting:

```
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.Variable(0.0, dtype=tf.float32)
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.9)
ema_op = ema.apply([w])

assigns = []

with tf.control_dependencies([ema_op]):
    for val in [10., 20., 40.]:
        assigns.append(tf.assign(w, tf.constant(val)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for assign in assigns:
        _, _, w_ = sess.run([ema_op, assign, ema.average(w)])
        print w_
    _, w_ = sess.run([ema_op, ema.average(w)])
    print w_
```

The resulting output is:

```
0.0
1.0000002
2.9000006
6.6100016
```

Comment: thank you very much. I tried to run your code, but got this result 

    0.0,
    0.0,
    1.0000002,
    2.9000006
Do you know why this happened?

Comment: Which version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0

Comment: I currently don't have any idea why you are getting these results. Did you change anything. You can run my code here to get the same results: https://repl.it/repls/ImaginativeValidExponent

Comment: @KeiraK I thing sess.run([...]) does not guarantee the order of execution. I have faced the same problem, and I post my modified code as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

This to update for https://stackoverflow.com/a/51192719/1497720, so that you will always get right output of

```
0.0
1.0000002
2.9000006
6.6100016
```

The code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
w = tf.Variable(0.0, dtype=tf.float32)
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.9)
ema_op = ema.apply([w])

assigns = []

with tf.control_dependencies([ema_op]):
    for val in [10., 20., 40.]:
        assigns.append(tf.assign(w, tf.constant(val)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for assign in assigns:
        sess.run(assign)
        print(sess.run(ema.average(w)))
    sess.run(ema_op)
    print(sess.run(ema.average(w)))
```